# Where can I find the implementation for atoi?

Tags: c

I want to find the implementation of the `atoi` function, but I dont know where to look. I looked at `/usr/include/stdlib.h`, found 2 references to `atoi`:

```
__extern_inline int
__NTH (atoi (const char *__nptr))
{
     return (int) strtol (__nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);
}
```

and:

```
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
     __THROW __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
```

I expected to find something like this:

```
int atoi (char* p)
{
    int result = 0;
     // working...
    return result;
}
```

References of `strtol` also points to something like `__THROW __nonnull ((1));`

So I can't understand how `atoi` is implemented.

Could you give some advices?

Comment: Is this plain curiosity? Or is there some actual problem that you need to solve? If there's an underlying problem, then please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: Anyway, if you're using GNU's libc, [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/atoi.c)'s the source. You'll be disappointed.

Comment: The first definition you show **is** an implementation of `atoi`. In it, `atoi` is implemented by calling `strtol`. You might then want to look for an implementation of `strtol`. However, the ultimate implementation will not be in `stdlib.h`, because headers are used only for declarations and simple implementations such as the one you found. To find full implementations, you need to look in the source code of the library, such as at the [link](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/atoi.c) that Federico klez Culloca provided.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Now I am looking at implementation of strtol and I am disappointed :) It is very difficult for me to understand it.
Yes, it was just plain curiosity.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html here is the location of libc for linux

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/strtol_l.c

Comment: "I am looking at implementation of strtol" and "it is very difficult for me to understand it. is vague. You need to post the code and provide detail as to what it difficult.

Comment: Anyway, if you want a more straightforward implementation, you can have a look at musl's [atoi](https://github.com/rofl0r/musl/blob/master/src/stdlib/atoi.c).

Comment: It sounds like you want a simple `atoi()/strtol()` implementation versus as robust one used is a real library.  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) has many learner implementations.  Many implementations suffer from UB when the result should be `INT_MIN` or with negative `char`. (including the one linked by [@FedericoklezCulloca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589481/where-can-i-find-the-implementation-for-atoi#comment95976451_54589481))

Comment: Implementation of function are usually **not** found in header files.

Comment: atoi is just a dangerous wrapper around strtol. Which is in turn a wrapper around various internal functions. Dig deep in the Glibc repo and you will find `__strtol_l`. Which is a horrible mess of pre-processor switches, unreadable to pretty much anyone.